# Typescript Exporting an object that implements an interface as default

Tags: typescript

I have a file called 'webpack.config.dev.ts'

When I started working with it I used:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'source-map-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }],
    },
    resolve: { extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"] }
};
```

This was fun for a while, but I wanted to type check my properties with the proper interface `webpack.Configuration`. I was hoping for something like:

```
export default:webpack.Configuration {devtools:'inline-source-map'}
```

That didn't work.

I tried:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

const config: webpack.Configuration =  {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'source-map-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }],
    },
    resolve: { extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"] }
};

export default config;
```

But then the file that was using it started giving errors.
The other file uses it as :

```
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
var y = config.output.publicPath;
```

This worked when I used the original method - but now it displays errors that config possibly undefined.

I'm using TypeScript 2.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
export default  { devtools: 'inline-source-map' } as webpack.Configuration;
```

You can also do:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
const config = { devtools: 'inline-source-map' } as webpack.Configuration;
export default config;
```

however, <s>not only is output undefined in your example...</s> its also typed as *optional* in `@types/webpack`

[image]

So, unless you type/cast your config as any, you need to check. Typescript is doing its job warning by you.

```
let output = config.output || { publicPath: "./some/default/path" };
let publicPath = output.publicPath;
```

Or of course you can use `if(config.output !== undefined) ...`

Comment: In my code output is defined - it's warning about the config - but thanks.

The solution itself doesn't help me - because when I do it your way - I get the same error - and I tried export default {...} as webpack.Configuration. 
But it didn't give me the intelisense I was looking for

Comment: hmm.. what is the error and where, because I don't get any errors and full intellisense.

Comment: I updated my question to include all the code - not just some of it.

When I use your method I get two problems:
In the other file - I get the error that config is possibly undefined. And in the config file - I don't get intelisense for the properties (devtools etc..)

Comment: My bad - all I needed was the as webpack.Configuration - to get what I wanted.
I'll edit your response with that.

Thanks

Comment: One more thing.
I don't get why the second option gave me the possibly undefined error.

Comment: My bad again - I got it - that's because in the interface output is optional so even though I specified it there is a risk of it not being set